# Free the memory of a pointer to a struct

Tags: c++, struct

I am new to `C++` and implemented the following `struct`:

```
struct Person {
  String name;
  int age;
};
```

Now I create a new object:

```
 Person *p = new Person();
 p->name = "name";
 p->age = 211;
```

and `push` it onto a `stack`:

```
 stack.push(*p);
```

I have a `while(!stack.empty())` expression and in there I process every element I pushed onto the stack.
Now where do I free the memory? In the `while`-loop I do the following:

```
Person *current = &stack.front();
stack.pop();
// do stuff
delete current;
```

Sadly, the `delete current` statement throws some kind of exception.

What do I do wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use `std::uniqur_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` and it'll be deleted for you automagically.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Not great advice if there's no reason for dynamic allocation.

Comment: You're pushing values in the `stack` container, but then threat them as pointers to objects from the heap. Then, trying to delete an object from the program stack (not to be confused with your `stack` container) crashes the program.

Comment: Is there some special reason you're using `new` here? Why not just `Person p; ... stack.push(p);`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need to `delete p` after pushing into the stack. The stack stores its own copy of the object pushed into it, so there is no need to do anything to it after popping.

But the real solution is to not use `new` in the first place:

```
Person p = {"name", 211};
...
stack.push(p);
```

or just

```
stack.push(Person{"name", 211});
```

Then

```
Person current = stack.front();
stack.pop();
```

So, no need to deal directly with memory management.

Comment: The stack stores its own copy of the object pushed into it on the `Stack` memory, right? What do I do if I don't have enough `Stack` memory since I push a lot of objects, around 40 000 000 `Person`?

Comment: @optional You'd probably get a `std::bad_alloc` exception.

Answer (score 4):

When you push something on to a stack, you don't push the original object - you push a *copy* of the object. To free the memory of the original object, you need to do it right at the point after you've pushed it.

Or you can skip that altogether and don't use `new` to create the object in the first place:

```
Person p;
p.name = "name";
p.age = 211;
stack.push(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make a pointer. If you have to, then use a smart pointer to free the memory for you: 
`std::unique_ptr<Person> p(new Person);`